# Dash manifest generation with subtitles

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I have already auto-generating code for dash manifests, it is not ffmpeg it makes manifest generation completely by itself (videos saved as bytes on my servers), which works correctly with player, but there isn't support for subtitles yet, I would want to allow users of my site to add external subtitles, which I will automatically convert to webvvt on my server and distribute by url through http.

Question/Task is:
Having url with webvvt (subtitles under it), to rewrite existing dash manifest, so to say I want to change autogeneration mechanism a little, with url of subtitles provided, to let my player display user's subtitles as well. I believe it should be quite easy, simply putting subtitles' url somewhere with special tags.

I've tried to find some information around about it, but haven't found anything worth to follow, really I need some simple example of dash-manifest with subtitles distributed by url inside, and it will be enough to customise my dash manifest code generation a somehow.

An example, I have manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT5.666S" minBufferTime="PT0.5S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011">
<Period id="0" start="PT0S" duration="PT5.666S">
    <AdaptationSet id="0" segmentAlignment="true" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
        <Representation id="0" bandwidth="122768" width="252" height="144" quality="mobile" frameRate="30" codecs="avc1.64000C,mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="44100" mimeType="video/mp4" startWithSAP="1">
            <BaseURL>some url to video</BaseURL>
            <SegmentBase indexRange="1343-1398">
                <Initialization range="0-1342"/>
            </SegmentBase>
        </Representation>
        <Representation id="1" bandwidth="359152" width="420" height="240" quality="lowest" frameRate="30" codecs="avc1.640015,mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="44100" mimeType="video/mp4" startWithSAP="1">
            <BaseURL>some url to video</BaseURL>
            <SegmentBase indexRange="1343-1398">
                <Initialization range="0-1342"/>
            </SegmentBase>
        </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
</Period>
</MPD>
```

How to put `https:www.some_site.com/sub1` here

Answer (score 1):

You can use external, non-segmented subtitles directly, there's an example on the [DASH-IF reference player](https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/v3.1.3/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html) page:

```
<AdaptationSet mimeType="text/vtt" lang="en"> 
    <Representation id="caption" bandwidth="123">
        <BaseURL>https:www.some_site.com/sub1</BaseURL> 
    </Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, already found it( will consider your answer as a right one